# How to remove exact text from a text file?

Tags: bash

I have a log.txt file that looks just like this.

```
2.txt
/home/test/2.txt
```

the file name followed by its original path, I want to update this log to remove these lines when that specific file is removed this is the snippet that does that.

```
if grep -Fxq "$var" log.txt
then
      result=$(grep -m2 "$var" log.txt | tail -n1 )
      mv $var $result
      grep -w $var log.txt > log.txt.tmp
fi
```

the first two lines work, it does move the file back
into its original directory.

this line here

```
grep -w $var log.txt > log.txt.tmp
```

puts what I want to remove from log.txt into a temporary text file. This isn't correct

I need to remove the result of

```
grep -w $var log.txt > log.txt.tmp
```

from the log.txt file but I can't seem to do that

I tried to remove the same contents from two files, but thats too slow and I don't want to sort everytime. There has to be an easier way. 
Thanks.

Basically the output would look like this.

```
2.txt
/home/2.txt
3.txt
/home/3.txt
```

if they decide to remove 2.txt (which already works) the new log.txt file would be

```
3.txt
/home/3.txt
```

I think it basically needs to search log.txt and remove the file name and the line under it.

```
sed -i "/$var/d" log.txt
```

I tried this out but it removes files with 1.txt in it as well so if a file is 11.txt it will remove that as well.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: So `sed -i "/$var/d" log.txt` IIUC

Comment: @daniu that works unfortunately it removes files with simialr names such 11.txt because 1.txt is in it :(

Comment: Then do `sed -i "/^$var/d" log.txt`. This forces the file name to start with the variable. Or, `sed -i "/^$var$/d" log.txt` to make a precise match.

Comment: @Anubis would this also remove the directory underneath the file name? since it contains the filename in the path?

Comment: If you are referring to the directory path below the filename, it won't because it does not get matched. Do you need to remove it as well ?

Comment: @Anubis yes I need to remove both of them if it makes it easier the path is ALWAYS one line underneath the file so maybe we can use that? like just delete the nextline as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if grep -Fxq "$var" log.txt
then
    result=$(grep -m2 "$var" log.txt | tail -n1 )
    echo mv $var $result
    sed -i '/'"${var//\./\\.}"'$/d' log.txt  # remove all the lines ending with $var value
fi
```

Note that, in general case, any period symbols (`.`) in `$var` needs to be escaped as a period can match any character in a regex match.

i.e. if `$var=2.txt`, then `sed -i '/2.txt/d' log.txt` matches `2.txt`, `2atxt` etc...

`${var//\./\\.}` is for escaping the period symbols so that above matches are avoided.

---

If the directory path is always following the line with filename, alternatively you can do a precise match with file name and remove both lines as follows.

```
sed -i '/^'"${var//\./\\.}"'$/,+1 d' log.txt
```

This might help if you have lines ending with the same file name, which you don't need to remove.

Comment: yeah its not changing the file content when running the sed command. I even ran it through the terminal.

Comment: did you set the `var` variable properly?

Comment: yes var is just the arguments from the user which would be the filenames its just this currently


for var in "$@"
do

which loops through all the arguments in the command line

Comment: This should work in any reasonably modern `sed` version.  Check whether following prints `1 4 5` (removing `2 3`): `seq 5 | sed '/2/,+1 d'`

Comment: Lol that actually works, but its still removing 11.txt because it still technucally ends in 1.txt very annoying bug :(

Comment: Try the second alternative, it will match exactly the given filename only.
`sed -i '/^'"${var//\./\\.}"'$/,+1 d' log.txt`